# Prove $f:[0,2] \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continous function where $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Prove $f:[0,2] \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function where $f(x) = \sqrt{x)}$ using a $\delta - \epsilon$ proof

Letting $a \in [0,2]$ and $\delta_0 = \frac{a}{2}$ gives $|x| \le \frac{3a}{2}$ and $\mid \sqrt{x} - \sqrt {a} \mid \le \mid \sqrt{x} - \sqrt {a} \mid \cdot\mid \sqrt{x} + \sqrt {a} \mid \le \delta_0\cdot 2\sqrt{2}\le \epsilon$ if $\delta < \frac{\epsilon}{2\sqrt{2}}$

Let $\epsilon > 0$ and find $\delta = \text{min}\{\delta_0, \frac{e}{2\sqrt{2}} \}$

Seems pretty straight forward but not sure I am correctly doing this. I wasn't sure what to use as the second possible choice for $\delta$ its been much more clear in other proofs I've done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $2\geq a > 0, |\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{a}| = \dfrac{|x-a|}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{a}}\leq \dfrac{|x-a|}{\sqrt{a}}<\dfrac{\delta}{\sqrt{a}}< \epsilon\iff \delta < \epsilon\cdot \sqrt{a}$. Thus this suggests that you choose $\delta = \dfrac{\epsilon\cdot \sqrt{a}}{2}$ will work.

If $a = 0, |\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{0}|= \sqrt{|x-0|}<\sqrt{\delta}<\epsilon\iff \delta < \epsilon^2$. Thus you can choose $\delta = \dfrac{\epsilon^2}{2}$ will work.

Comment: For $0<a\le 2$, $\delta =\sqrt{a}\epsilon$ suffices; obviously a smaller value of $\delta $ works too.  And if $a=0$, then $\delta=\epsilon^2$ suffices; obviously any smaller $\delta $ work too.